# Are "car camping" questions on topic here?

Tags: discussion, scope

For example, [this question](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/492/which-will-keep-my-food-colder-longer-draining-the-melted-ice-water-or-leaving) about ice in a cooler.  I am afraid that if we open the site to questions like that, soon we will have questions about RV's and campers and portable gazebos and whatnot.

Answer (score 16):

As far as I'm concerned it's on topic - it's still the outdoors!

Answer (score 11):

As long as they're relevant to the outdoors/camping side. We don't want questions like "What is the cheapest gas station between Reno and Tucson?". And I'm on the fence about things like recharging electronics while car camping.