# List of everything that has been declared on or off topic on the Outdoors.SE

Tags: discussion, scope

It would be nice to get a list of all of the topics that have been declared on or off-topic in one place.

What I am thinking is a community wiki list with the name of the topic and a link to the meta post where it was decided.

**I am trying to only do this for topics that have a clear consensus**, where it would be obvious to anyone who read the meta post that it is either on or off-topic (like this [one](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/are-questions-about-gold-panning-as-a-hobby-or-sport-on-topic)). Otherwise, I will put them into the Contentious/Unanswered category.

Two notes,

- For things like camping that don't have a meta post but do have lots of questions, I am simply going to link to the [tag page](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/camping).
- Please keep the topics alphabetized for easier access.

Answer (score 6):

### On Topic

- [Archery](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/768/which-archery-sports-are-on-topic-on-tgo)
- [Backpacking](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/backpacking)
- [Beachcombing](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316/is-beachcombing-on-topic)
- [Birding/Ornithology/Bird Watching](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181/should-birding-be-on-topic-on-tgo)
- [Book Recommendations](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123/is-asking-for-recommendations-of-books-ok)
- [Bouldering](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bouldering)
- [Camping](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/camping)
- [Canoeing](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11/does-outdoors-include-sailing-climbing-kayaking-and-other-pursuits?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [Car Camping](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60/are-car-camping-questions-on-topic-here)
- [Caving](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/341/caving-proposal)
- [Finding specific, previously read books](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1008/would-it-be-okay-to-ask-for-help-finding-specific-books-ive-previously-read-bu)
- [Fishing](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fishing)
- [Fly tying](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/643/are-questions-on-fly-tying-making-fly-fishing-flies-on-topic)
- [Geocaching](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/463/geocaching-scope)
- [Gold Panning](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/are-questions-about-gold-panning-as-a-hobby-or-sport-on-topic)
- [Hiking](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hiking)
- [Historical questions](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/414/historical-questions)
- [Hitch hiking](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/498/is-hitchhiking-on-topic)
- [Hunting](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42/are-hunting-questions-on-topic-for-the-great-outdoors)
- [Identification](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification)

  - [Animal Identification](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/animal-identification)
  - [Bug Identification](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug-identification)
  - [Gear Identification](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gear-identification)
  - [Knot Identification](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/knot-identification)
  - [Manmade-object Identification](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manmade-object-identification)
  - [Mountain Identification](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/16972/what-species-of-dinosaur-made-these-3-toed-6-inch-long-tracks)
  - [Plant Identification](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plant-identification)
  - [Tree Identification](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tree-identification)
- [Indoor Climbing](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170/does-indoor-climbing-belong-on-tgo)
- [Kayaking](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11/does-outdoors-include-sailing-climbing-kayaking-and-other-pursuits?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [Knots and Knot tying](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221/should-knots-and-knot-tying-be-in-scope)
- [Legality](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48/should-questions-about-legality-be-allowed)
- [Make-shift adventure gear](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/432/are-questions-related-to-building-a-make-shift-adventure-gear-valid-on-this-si)
- [Military style obstacle courses](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/948/would-this-question-be-considered-on-topic)
- [Mountaineering](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mountaineering)
- [Off Road Driving](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/205/is-off-roading-4x4-on-topic?rq=1)
- [Orienteering](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/236/does-orienteering-questions-belong-here)
- [Rafting](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11/does-outdoors-include-sailing-climbing-kayaking-and-other-pursuits?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [Rail Biking](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/892/would-railbiking-be-on-topic)
- [Rappelling](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rappelling)
- [Repairing outdoor clothing or footwear](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/403/are-questions-on-repairing-typical-outdoors-clothes-and-footwear-ontopic)
- [River Navigation](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/576/is-river-navigation-in-scope)
- [Rock Climbing](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rock-climbing)
- [Route Setting](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/route-setting)
- [Running](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/running)
- [Sailboat building plans](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271/would-asking-for-sailboats-buildingplan-resources-be-considered-on-topic)
- [Sailing](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sailing)
- [Scuba Diving](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439/are-scuba-diving-questions-on-topic)
- [Shuttle services](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/395/is-asking-about-shuttle-services-for-trail-heads-off-topic)
- [Skiing](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/skiing)
- [Snowboarding](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/snowboarding)
- [Skydiving](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64/would-skydiving-questions-be-considered-on-topic)
- [Specific hikes](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/528/are-questions-about-specific-hikes-on-topic)
- [Sports climbing](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sport-climbing)
- [Survival Food](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/248/do-the-questions-about-survival-food-belong-here)
- [Swimming](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/swimming)
- [Tracking](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1163/are-questions-about-tracking-on-topic-for-this-site?cb=1)
- [Trail Running](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/328/is-trail-running-an-appropriate-topic-here)
- [Trekking](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trekking)
- [Urban Exploration](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/479/is-urban-exploration-on-topic)
- [What bit me](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/811/would-a-what-bit-me-question-be-on-topic)
- [Wildlife](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wildlife)

### Off-Topic

- [Bee keeping](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/848/would-questions-about-beekeeping-and-colonising-be-on-topic-and-desired-here?rq=1)
- [Best / cheapest place to purchase something](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95/is-asking-the-best-cheapest-place-to-purchase-something-off-topic)
- [Tree care](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/851/tree-care-better-here-or-gardening)

### Contentious/Unanswered

- [Pistol/Rifle shooting, air gun shooting](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/760/which-sports-need-to-be-discussed/762#762) (see [Should we revisit or enforce that pistols are off topic?](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1113/should-we-revisit-or-enforce-that-pistols-are-off-topic))
- [Gear list reviews](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/468/are-gear-list-review-questions-on-topic)
- [General Sightseeing](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/980/is-general-sightseeing-on-topic?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [Interaction with people](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/677/are-questions-about-interaction-with-people-on-topic)
- [Mountain Biking](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176/do-mountain-biking-questions-belong-here)
- [On road driving](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/981/is-on-road-driving-on-topic)
- [Outdoor animals/pests in the house or yard](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1007/how-should-we-handle-questions-about-outdoor-animals-usually-pests-that-are-in?rq=1)
- [Parkour](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200/parkour-on-or-off-topic)
- [Prescription drug advice](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/555/should-prescription-drug-advice-be-on-topic)
- [Tangential Nutrition](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/280/is-tangential-nutrition-off-topic)
- [Things related to a zoo?](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/850/can-i-ask-questions-about-things-related-to-a-zoo)
- [Weather forecasting](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/716/weather-forecasting-on-topic)

Comment: I moved Mountain-Biking to Contentious - we have so many things that we explicitly declare on topic even though they fit perfectly in another SE community. I think nobody can seriously say that mountain-biking is only done inside. Also rail biking is on topic.

Comment: I remember tennis being declared off topic, and also sports like football which, although played outdoors require a lot of man-made infrastructure and have a large commercial component.

Comment: @ab2 Looking at the meta posts its complicated and I really only want to list the ones that are definitely off or on topic. It might be worth revisiting to get a clear answer, but I don't think there is any interest in those topics.

Comment: What about mountain identification?

Comment: https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mountain-identification

Comment: @Ricketyship  I think that at the time it was “officially” off topic but I will add it