# Is Freediving on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Swimming is on topic, scuba diving is on topic, so I have no reason to believe, freediving should be off topic.

But since it's not listed on [List of everything that has been declared on or off topic on the Outdoors.SE](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1025/list-of-everything-that-has-been-declared-on-or-off-topic-on-the-outdoors-se), I'm asking for canonical link:

Is Freediving on topic?

Comment: I can't see any reason why it shouldn't be.It could also be on topic on Sports.SE.

Comment: It can be added to the on topic list, if you can not edit it in yourself, please post a comment with a link as those in the list under that list and ping mod to edit it in for you.